# Define and convert datetime in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, timezone, amazon-athena

I have a process where I need to to match UTC datetime and EDT datetime.

As you know, EDT can be changed between 4/5 hours from UTC.
How can I define one datetime to be in UTC and another to be in EDT and match the two?

Something like (datetime_A is my EDT timestamp, and datetime_B is my UTC):

```
Where CAST((datetime_A as EDT) to UTC)=datetime_B
```

Thanks!

Comment: So do you already have an EDT date as column?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron - Yes, I have an EDT column - and a UTC column. But I don't want to manually check IF EDT+4 = UTC, I want to be able to define a timestamp in a specific timezone, and compare to other